# PHP - $_FILES not appearing

Tags: php, file, post

I have a fairly simple form on my site. Just a text input and a file input.

```
<form action='myFile.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' id='image_description' name='image_description'>
    <input type='file' id='image' name='image'>
    <button onclick="this.form.submit();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit I have `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_FILES)`.

I can see everything I entered in the text fields but the file does not seem to be coming through.

```
array(2) {
    ["image_description"]=> string(4) "test"
    ["image"]=> string(14) "Untitled-1.png"
}

array(0) {

}
```

This is happening both locally on WAMP and on my shared hosting domain.

Any ideas or possible reasons this could be happening or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `enctype` is missing.

Comment: @Script47... thanks I knew that and everything... been staring at the screen too long... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add  in your Form

enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate, No need to post an answer to it.